# Program to remove \n characters ,2 ways to do the same idea but have different results

Tags: c

first program

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
void delete_n(char x[]){
    int len = strlen(x);
    // TITV\n\0 => TITV\0\0
    if(x[len-1]=='\n'){
        x[len-1]='\0';
    }
}

int main(){

    char name[50];
    printf("your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
    delete_n(name);
    printf("\nYour name : %s", name);
    printf("\nlen = %d", strlen(name));
    

}
```

2nd program

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
void delete_n(char x[]){
    int len = strlen(x);
    // TITV\n\0 => TITV\0\0
    if(x[len]=='\n'){
        x[len]='\0';
    }
}

int main(){

    char name[50];
    printf("your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
    delete_n(name);
    printf("\nYour name : %s", name);
    printf("\nlen = %d", strlen(name));
    

}
```

why is the length of the string in the 2nd program unchanged as in the first program

both programs aim to delete \n then measure the length of the string

this is images you can see result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNjcQ.png)

Comment: 2nd program reads the `'\0'`. Valid indexes are `0 <= i < len`. It is defined -- just not what you want.

Comment: Why do you think they're the same when the second one doesn't subtract 1?

Comment: The `if` condition in the second one will never be true. `x[len]` contains `'\0'`.

Comment: Generally speaking, people use `name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';` instead of writing their own function.

Comment: The first program causes UB when an empty string is passed: `echo -n "" | ./program`

Comment: if I fgets... TITV  , strlen will show 5 . That mean T : 0 , I : 1 ,T : 2 , V : 3 , /n : 4 , /0 : 5 (I think so but not sure )and for will go 0 -- 5 ( 5 is result strlen ) , it right ? , if name[4] it will change to /0

Comment: `strlen` returns `size_t`, not `int`, and `size_t` should be printed using `%zu`, not `%d`. Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: @NgocAnh The first program changes `x[4]` to `\0`, removing the newline. The second program writes `\0` to `x[5]`, but `x[5]` was already `\0`, so the second program doesn't remove the newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second program does not remove the `\n`. You can test it yourself

```
int main(){

    char name[50];
    printf("your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
    delete_n(name);
    for(char *p = name; *p; p++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *p);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5GWK48rcc

```
your name: 84 73 84 86 10
```

The first function is also incorrect. It will fail if the string is `0` chars long. The type for length is also wrong.

```
void delete_n(char *x)
{
    if(x && *x)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(x);
        if(x[len - 1]=='\n')
        {
            x[len - 1]='\0';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(x[len]=='\n')` is always false, so 2nd program does not remove any `'\n'`.

Given `int len = strlen(x);`, `x[len]` contains `'\0'`.

---

Corner cases: `x[len-1]` risks undefined behavior (UB) should `fgets()` as `len == 0` is possible.   Uncommonly, `fgets()` may first read a _null character.

```
//if(x[len-1]=='\n'){
// Better as 
if(len > 0 && x[len-1] == '\n'){
    x[--len]='\0';  // Reduce length
}
```

or use

```
// Remove trailing \n if there or not.
x[strcspn(x, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Comment: @0___________ Good eye, Code amended.